# Is it possible to set rider as difftool in GitExtensions?

Tags: rider, git-extensions, mergetool, difftool

I couldn't find information on google whether you can assign the rider as a diff and merge tool in GitExtensions. [There is no such option in GitExtensions by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jePak.jpg)

On GitHub Gist, there is only one [mention](https://gist.github.com/johnnyasantoss/f0a99283a6ef428365e0cd5eab7ae99d) of setting up rider as a global diffftool. However, even if the path to rider64.exe is specified correctly, and [GitExtensions itself sees Rider as a diffftool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8UK4.jpg), nothing happens when you try to run the application. Regardless of whether the IDE is open or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also searched for this solution and came across the same [mention](https://gist.github.com/johnnyasantoss/f0a99283a6ef428365e0cd5eab7ae99d). After several attempts, I finally managed to do it :)

```
# Diff with JetBrains Rider
[diff]
    tool = rider
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "rider"]
    cmd = \"C:/your_path/rider64.exe\" diff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path = C:/your_path/rider64.exe

# Merge with JetBrains Rider
[merge]
    tool = rider
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
[mergetool "rider"]
    cmd = \"C:/your_path/rider64.exe\" merge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
    path = C:/your_path/rider64.exe
    trustExitCode = true
```

I made it globally in

> C:\Users\your_user\.gitconfig